# ASP.NETCore 3.0 Dropdownlist error - InvalidOperationException: There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>' that has the key

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

I have this code that works in my previous projects asp.net core 2.0 and 2.2 , its a dropdownlist with auto postback

However in adding them to my recent 3.0 project I get the following errors below. Here is my code and the errors, please advise

thanks

Ehi

Error message

```
InvalidOperationException: There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>' that has the key "Cat"
```

Showing all Categories
            @Html.DropDownList("Cat", ViewBag.DepartmentID as IEnumerable, "Show all Departments", new { onchange = "form.submit();", @class = "form-control-textbox-dropdownlist" })

my razor view page

```
@Html.DropDownList("Cat", ViewBag.DepartmentID as IEnumerable<SelectListItem>, "Show all Departments", new { onchange = "form.submit();", @class = "form-control-textbox-dropdownlist" })
```

and controller

```
   ViewData["DepartmentID"] = new SelectList(_context.Set<Models.Department.Departments> (), "SubCategory_Name", "SubCategory_Name");
```

Answer (score 0):

This might seem a bit weird but Html helpers are to be replaced by tag helpers and more so, the ASP.NET Core 3.0 Preview docs do not include Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering.IHtmlHelper Interface docs. However it would just be easier to use the tag helper. You can replace the @Html code with the following and it should work.

```
<select asp-for="Cat" asp-items="ViewBag.DepartmentID"></select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to make the following changes :

```
@Html.DropDownList("DepartmentID", ViewBag.DepartmentID as IEnumerable<SelectListItem>, "Show all Departments", new { onchange = "form.submit();", @class = "form-control-textbox-dropdownlist" })
```

The name of the dropdown ("DepartmentID") will be used when you post back your data to the server. But you'd better make the name of the dropdown be consistent with the ViewData and ViewBag .